# Remove all certificate authorities from a Firefox profile

Tags: firefox, certificate, certificate-authority

Objective is to trust only certain certificates stored on the hard disk for that certain profile. Thus no certificate authorities are needed.

Tried without success:

- Delete all CAs using Certificate Manager (part of Firefox Preferences)
- Delete `cert9.db` in the profile
- Clear `cert9.db` to 0 bytes and remove all permission flags so that Firefox may not change it

All three measures led to the CAs reappear (though not necessarily in `cert9.db`, at least if I removed write permissions to that file; but still in Certificate Manager of Firefox).

I wonder where the CAs come from. Does Firefox read them from the Internet if it misses them? I did not expect them to reappear at all.

How can I prevent that behavior?

Comment: Why is this question downvoted? If you think it is the wrong community for suchlike questions, please let me know.

Comment: Starting with Firefox 58, several data files have been changed. `cert8.db` changed to `cert9.db`, `key3.db` changed to `key4.db` and others, with new formats. Firefox will fallback to the older versions if you remove the newer SQLite versions. Questions: (1) Is the Firefox installation new and clean? (2) Do you have these older files which might be where the CAs are coming from?

Comment: The installation of that special profile is new and contains exactly 2 `db` files: `cert9.db` and `key4.db`. Because it is a special use case, I created a new profile. The installation of Firefox is controlled by the `apt` package manager. Initially it was installed one or more years ago but solely changed by updates because those files are not user-writable and I did never edit them with `root` permissions.

Comment: Does it really happen if you distrust the CAs?

Comment: It happens if I click "Delete or Distrust...". The list becomes completely empty. But is full again if I re-open Certificate Manager.

Comment: Questions: (1)Does it happen if you use Firefox with add-ons disabled by using the command `firefox -safe-mode`? (2) What is your operating system?

Comment: Following your suggestion I started Firefox through `firefox -safe-mode -P no-ca-profile`. Beforehand I deleted `cert9.db`, but it immediately re-appeared after launching Firefox. Then I deleted the first two CAs in Certificate Manager (using "Delete or Distrust...") they disappeared from the list. After killing and restarting Firefox, both deleted CAs were on the list again. Operating system is Ubuntu.

Comment: Just to verify : You did all these operations in safe-mode?

Comment: All operations in safe mode. However, there are no add-ons installed on my Firefox. Thus safe mode should not have any effect.

Comment: In Certificate Manager, have you also deleted the certificates in the Servers section?

Comment: I had two certificates in the Servers section. Deleted them, afterwards deleted all CAs, but still they all re-appeared (except for the two certificates in the Servers section).

Comment: I give up. Well, at least we managed to kill two of them. To debug, you will probably need to trace the Internet requests of Firefox.

Comment: One last thought: Are these certificates coming from the operating system (and which is yours)?

Comment: What about to make those files 0 bytes and deny the permission to write (or read)? Then you have eventually to manage the error... `:-)` _/dev/null/_ thinking...   (under linux to link them to `/dev/null`...).

Comment: Give it a look in `about:config`. Start filtering with `cert`. There are some options that can force what you are describing... maybe the default `services.sync.prefs.sync.security.default_personal_cert;true` should be better false... and others... have a nice hunt... (Just to honor my name I preferred the above solution...). Ps> let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Is there a way to remove all CA certificates in Firefox?

Firefox uses Mozilla's [NSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS) libraries for security related features like TLS. NSS has it's own builtin CA store, which is used by Firefox to obtain the default CA certificates.

From [Mozilla's FAQ](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA/FAQ):

> The pre-loaded CA certificates are included in the following files:
>
> - Windows: libnssckbi.dll
> - Unix, Linux, and other *nix variants: libnssckbi.so
> - Mac OS X: Contents/MacOS/libnssckbi.dynlib

Therefore it is not possible to remove all CA certificates as they are part of Firefox itself.

### Is it possible to strip all CA certificates of all trust?

From [Mozilla's FAQ](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA/FAQ):

> If you don't trust a particular CA whose root certificate is included
>   by default in Mozilla products, then there are two ways to disable the
>   certificate.
>
> 1. Turn off the trust bits for that root certificate.
> 2. Delete the root certificate.
>
>    - Deleting a root certificate that is in the default root store is equivalent to turning off all of the trust bits for that root.
>        Therefore, even though the root certificate will re-appear in the
>        Certificate Manager, it will be treated as though you changed the
>        trust bits of that root certificate to turn them all off.
>
> **Important:** This change will have a permanent affect, such that the
>   trust bits for the root certificate can only be changed again by you.
>   This change will not be affected by upgrading to newer versions of
>   Mozilla software. It is strongly recommended that you note which root
>   certificate you modify, so that you can turn the trust bits back on if
>   the change negatively impacts your browsing experience.

So to distrust all CA certificates:

1. Goto `about:preferences#privacy`
2. Click on `View Certificates...` at the bottom of the page
3. Switch to the tab `Authorities`
4. Select a certificate
5. Click on `Delete or Distrust...`
6. Confirm by clicking on `OK`
7. Repeat steps 4-6 for every certificate
8. Restart Firefox

After you restart Firefox you will see that all default certificates have reappeared.

### Why do CA certificates keep reappearing after a restart of Firefox?

Default certificates cannot be removed and so Firefox only distrusts them which has the effect that they cannot be used to verify other certificates. You can select a CA certificate and click `Edit Trust...` to see that nothing is checked once you distrusted it.
A distrust has the same effect as deleting the certificate itself except that the certificate will still be shown in the Certificate Manager.

For more information: [Changing Trust Settings](https://wiki.mozilla.org/PSM:Changing_Trust_Settings#Changing_Root_Certificate_Trust_Settings)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Firefox has some CAs built into the code.

From [CA/FAQ](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA/FAQ):

> These pre-loaded root CA certificates are distributed with Mozilla and
>   related software in the form of a shared library installed on users'
>   systems along with the rest of the software executable code. They can
>   therefore be updated when new versions of the software are released.
>
> The pre-loaded CA certificates are included in the following files:
>
> - Windows: libnssckbi.dll
> - Unix, Linux, and other *nix variants: libnssckbi.so
> - Mac OS X: Contents/MacOS/libnssckbi.dynlib

If these are the certificates you are trying to delete, then the answer
is negative, as they are built into the code and are not stored in
any `.db` file (to start with).
You might try to hack these files, but even if you succeed, you will
need to repeat the hack for every new release of Firefox.

---

I have found another setting which might be responsible for the store being 
populated by certificates coming from the operating system, although perhaps
only implemented for Windows : `security.enterprise_roots.enabled`.

There is no information on how this `about:config` setting is implemented now,
although from the article it is clear that it is still evolving.
I suggest to test if it is set in your case.

From the Mozilla article
[CA:AddRootToFirefox](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA:AddRootToFirefox):

> As of version 49, Firefox can be experimentally configured to
>   automatically search for and import CAs that have been added to the
>   Windows certificate store by a user or administrator. To do so, set
>   the preference "**security.enterprise_roots.enabled**" to **true**. In this
>   mode, Firefox will inspect the
>   `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SystemCertificates` registry location
>   (corresponding to the API flag `CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE`) for
>   CAs that are trusted to issue certificates for TLS web server
>   authentication. Any such CAs will be imported and trusted by Firefox,
>   although note that they may not appear in the Firefox's certificate
>   manager. It is expected that administration of these CAs (e.g. trust
>   configuration) will occur via built-in Windows tools or other 3rd
>   party utilities. Note also that for such changes to take effect in
>   Firefox either the preference will have to be toggled off and on again
>   or Firefox will have to be restarted. As this feature evolves, this
>   may be handled automatically for ease of use.